# Anagrams of a word in Ada Programming

Tags: ada

How can I get anagrams of a word in ada programming. For example:

I have a string 'one'. How can it be jumbled into 'neo' or 'eon' etc?

example code:

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   WordText  : String (1 .. 80);
   Last : Natural;

begin
   Put_Line("Enter Text: ");
   Get_Line (WordText, Last);

   -- example: I entered 'one' 
   -- it must be shuffle text per character   
   -- then it will print shuffled text: 'neo' or 'eno' or 'oen' etc.
   Put_Line ("Text Shuffle: " &WordText (1 .. Last));

end Main;
```

Comment: For future reference, please add code examples to explain what approaches you've already tried. This helps us give more relevant suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: You have a good start on the framework, but you've shown nothing that attempts to solve the actual problem. As it stands, you're essentially asking us to solve the problem for you.

Answer (score 2):

Implement one of the jumble algorithms described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2722124/230513) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Jumble&oldid=424282124). For example,

0. For each word in a dictionary, sort its constiuent letters, preserving duplicates. Use an instance of [`Ada.Containers.Generic_Array_Sort`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-18-26.html) to sort the letters.
1. Create a hash map; enter the sorted string as the map's key; add the original word to the set of words that are permutatively equivalent, and use the set as the map's value. Use an instance of [`Ada.Containers.Ordered_Sets`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-18-9.html) to hold the set of words. Use an instance of [`Ada.Containers.Hashed_Maps`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-18-5.html) for the map.
2. For a given string, sort its letters, look up the mapped set and print the words it contains.

A complete example is seen [here](https://github.com/trashgod/roots#word-jumble).